# GROUP_BY in multi-table query not returning null parts

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 tables:

people table (t1)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | jon |
| 2 | brian |
| 3 | james |
| 4 | jane |

tags table (t2)

| id | tag | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tall | height |
| 2 | short | height |
| 3 | fat | weight |
| 4 | skinny | weight |

tags_to_people table (t3)

| id | tagId | peopleId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |

The tags_to_people table provides a mapping of tags to people, so the idea here is that tagId references the tag table, and peopleId references the people table. The desired output is the following:

| id | name | tagList |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jon | [{"type": "height", "tag": "tall"}] |
| 2 | brian | [{"type": "height", "tag": "tall"}, {"type": "height", "tag": "short"}, {"type": "weight", "tag": "fat"}] |
| 3 | james | [{"type": "height", "tag": "tall"}, {"type": "weight", "tag": "skinny"}] |
| 4 | jane | [] |

I've tried a bunch of queries, this one brings me the closest:

```
SELECT t1.*, CONCAT(
  '[',
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'type', t2.type,
      'value', t2.value
    )
  ),
  ']'
) AS tagList
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t3 d ON t1.id = t3.peopleId
LEFT JOIN t2 c ON t3.tagId = t2.id
GROUP BY COALESCE(t1.id);
```

this query almost works except it doesn't include the last row with the empty array(I thought COALESCE would solve the issue but it isn't).

Any idea what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (the best way - create online fiddle).

Comment: Use JSON_ARRAYAGG() instead of CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this query

```
SELECT t1.*, CONCAT(
  '[',
    if(t3.peopleid is null,"",
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'type', t2.type,
      'tag', t2.tag
    )
  )),
  ']'
) AS tagList
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t3  ON t1.id = t3.peopleId
LEFT JOIN t2  ON t3.tagId = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Output:

```
|  1 | jon   | [{"type": "height", "tag": "tall"}]                                                                     |
|  2 | brian | [{"type": "height", "tag": "tall"},{"type": "height", "tag": "short"},{"type": "weight", "tag": "fat"}] |
|  3 | james | [{"type": "weight", "tag": "skinny"},{"type": "height", "tag": "tall"}]                                 |
|  4 | jane  | []                                                                                      |
```